# Validate body of a POST request in django

Tags: python, django

I have a view in django that sign's up a client and I have a model for the client and a form that looks like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from api.models.client import Client


class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

In my view I would like to validate the data in the request but my problem is that the paramters in the request are camelCase and not snake_case so when I try to validate the data it doesn't work.

```
def sign_up(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    form = SignUpForm(body)
    print(form.is_valid())
    return HttpResponse('this is a test response')
```

Is there a clean way of making this work? Also is this the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: why are the parameters in camel case?

Comment: @sayse I'm rewriting the APIs of an existing server written in Nodejs which is used by a mobile app so I don't want to change the mobile app to support snake case

Comment: Can you please add an example of incoming request params?

Comment: @heemayl It's just the form but in camelCase: `{"firstName": "abc", "lastName": "dajsd"}`. I have more complicated forms with many params so I can't rename them manually

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the body keys, use regex to rename the key and adding to a new dictionary.

```
def camel_to_snake(val):
    return re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'_\1', val).lower()

body = json.loads(request.body)
new_body = {camel_to_snake(k): v for k, v in body.items()}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comments, I don't want to rename the params manually

Comment: @ninesalt maybe include all the details in the OP next time. You can use regex instead of manually mapping